# How do I stop someone from unhiding my Excel sheets?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

First I have hide all sheets in "very hidden" mode using VBA editor, and protect my VBA project with password. But problem is I can easily unhide all sheets simply by entering vba code in immediate window which is:

```
for each sh in worksheets:sh.visible=true:next sh
```

So which is the efficient way so that no one can unhide my sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Try Excel>Review>'Protect Workbook' (Structure) >Password
additional with the protection of your VBA-Code.
If you try to change the .visible, Excel will not allow this.

Comment: This does not work. The *'Protect Workbook'* can easily be removed with VBA without knowing the password. And then you can unhide whatever you want with VBA too.

Comment: Yes. Also you can remove the password manualy in the XML. 
But you can't use the immediate window without "illegal" password remove to unhide the sheet (as discribed in your question).

Comment: No, you actually can remove the password with only one single VBA line in the immediate window easily. This is possible due to an unfixed bug (since at least Excel 2010 up to the latest version). The bug is reported to Microsoft but they don't care since they don't consider it a security break. So I need only 2 lines of code to make hidden sheets visible again. And there is no way to prevent that yet.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't.

Anyone who can code VBA can unhide them. Hiding worksheets is not a security feature! It is just to hide something for convinience or not *accidentally* change something.

You can't prevent unhiding worksheets. Anyone who can open the worksheet will be able to make data in hidden worksheets visible.

The absoulute only way to secure data is to not hand out this data to any users. Therefore a way could be to have the raw data on a server database that allows users to send a request and returns a result (but never the raw data).